# Problem when updating google-ads library on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pypi, google-cloud-composer, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to update the version of the pypi package google-ads on Google Cloud Composer.

I need to update google-ads to version 19.0.0, which is required to update the version of Google ads API to v12.
When I try to set the version to 19.0.0, version problems start to appear with other libraries, mainly the mysql-connector-python, which is native from composer.

Someone have any sugestions about what I can try?
Here is some information about the environment that I'm using.
Composer version 2.1.7 | Airflow version 2.4.3

I already tried to change the versions of the conflicting libraries, but mysql-connector-python requires an old version of protobuf and google-ads needs a new one, I stay trapped between those two.

Another attempt was deleting the library mysql-connector-python, which the following **cli on cloud shell:** gcloud --project=data-engineering-325514 composer environments update teste --location us-central1 --remove-pypi-packages mysql-connector-python

**But I got the following error:**

> (gcloud.composer.environments.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: No change in configuration. Must specify a change to configuration.software_configuration.pypi_dependencies.mysql-connector-python

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in the new Composer version ([2.1.10](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#March_18_2023)) which comes with google-ads==20.0.0 ported so it is compatible with the older protobuf (and hence mysql connector as well).

Best,

Michal

Answer (score 0):

The error you got can be ignored since it was an expected behavior.

Regarding the compatibility of your **google-ads version**, it is best to upgrade it to `20.0.0 version (composer-2.1.10-airflow-2.4.3)` which uses `Python version 3.8.12` same as the **composer-2.1.7-airflow-2.4.3**.